# USB Drive not Recognized

Tags: macos, usb

I have a new usb, I plugged in, it worked, then I formatted it in Mac OS X Extended. It gave some error, and then it disappear from everywhere. Tried it an other PC with Linux, not working in OS X El Capitan. Don't know what to do.

Any help? Usb not showing anywhere. not in disk utility not in system report. Search but won't find any solution yet.

**UPDATE:**
I tried Diskpart on windows. It worked, shows my hard drive and the usb drive however the usb (disk1) has the status "no media" and a size of "0B"

I could select it however "clean" resulted in "Virtual Disk Service error: There is no media in the device" and "create partition primary" resulted in another error stating that there is not enough space to create a partition. Tried formatting gives error "There is no volume selected."

Comment: "some error"... what error? "Tried it an other PC with Linux" ... & the result was?

Comment: Some Write fail error came, i just ignore and wanted to retry , but then it stopped showing, and not showing on any other PC as well.

Comment: a complete guess... it claimed to be something big like 64GB, but when formatted it suddenly failed? My first guess would be fake 'big' USB drive, but idk how to correctly test for that.

Comment: @Tetsujin its 8gb HP 250w USB. and it fails while diskutility is erasing it.

Comment: then second guess would be, it's a DOA, send it back. USB sticks [& SD cards] are not worth fighting once they fail. I deal with hundreds of them for work, if they won't format they go in the bin.

Comment: :/ I can't I got it free from a conference.

Comment: There ya go then... worth every penny ;-)